# Laravel 5.2 Validation Error not appearing in blade

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, server-side-validation

I want to show validation Error in View page while user giving wrong input. It's Ok that it's not saving anything in database while a user giving wrong input. But there is no error message in user view page. If anyone find the error, please help me out.

Here is the controller:

```
public function saveUser(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|max:120',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'phone' => 'required|min:11|numeric',
            'course_id'=>'required'
            ]);

        $user = new User();
        $user->name=  $request->Input(['name']);
        $user->email=  $request->Input(['email']);
        $user->phone=  $request->Input(['phone']);
        $user->date = date('Y-m-d');
        $user->completed_status = '0';
        $user->course_id=$request->Input(['course_id']);
        $user->save();
       return redirect('success');         
    }
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('index');
    })->name('main');

      Route::post('/saveUser',[
        'uses' => 'AppController@saveUser',
        'as'=>'saveUser',
        ]);
    });
```

Here is the blade view page:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')
Create User
@endsection
@section('content')
@include('partials.message-block')
        <div class="container" >

            <h3> Student Register </h3>

        {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'saveUser','class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST'))  !!}
      {!! Form::token(); !!}
      {!!   csrf_field() ; !!} 

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required placeholder="Name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required placeholder="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Phone Number</label>          
          <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" required placeholder="phone">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Class</label>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="course_id" >
            @foreach($input as $row)
            <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>  

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>

@endsection
```

And here is the error-message block:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 error">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
@if(Session::has('message'))
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md--offset-4 success">
        {{Session::get('message')}}
    </div>
</div>

@endif
```

Comment: Try to remove `web` middleware if you're using 5.2.27 or higher.

Comment: thanks for the help now it's working! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ErrorBag is always empty in Laravel 5.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377420/errorbag-is-always-empty-in-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try to remove `web` middleware if you're using 5.2.27 or higher. The thing is now Laravel automatically applies `web` middleware to all routes inside `routes.php` and if you're trying to add it manually you can get errors.

`app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` of the 5.2.27 version now adds web middleware to all routes inside `routes.php`:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you take a look on this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826362/laravel-associate-method-is-returning-empty-array-in-the-view)

Answer (score 1):

Use Below line in your controller

**use Validator;**

Add below code in your controller function where your request is sent.

```
$validator  =   Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'fname'     =>  'required|max:20|min:4',
     'uemail'    =>  'required|email',
     'message'   =>  'required',
 ]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
if ($validator->fails()) {
       $messages = $validator->messages();
       return Redirect::back()->withErrors($messages)->withInput($request->all()); 
 }
```

In your view page

```
 @if ($errors->any())
   <label for="fname" class="error">{{ $errors->first('fname') }}</label> 
 @endif
```

For display individual field wise error.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using laravel 5.2+ then please use the below code.

Moved `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` and `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` from web `$middlewareGroups` to `$middleware` in `app\Http\Kernel.php`

Answer (score 0):

Alexey is correct and if you're not comfortable with that then you can just add this code into your view for the session messages to show.

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
        @endif
        @if(count($errors)>0)

            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li class="alert alert-danger">{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        @endif
```

I've done this in laravel 5.5. Please do confirm if this helps you out.