# Laravel route group page redirects to home

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

I have installed Laravel and set up authentication and I have also created a route group like this:

```
// users that want to access test route should be logged in. 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::get('first', function () {
        return 'first';
    });
});
```

The problem is when I access the route like this:

```
http://localhost/first
```

I can see my "first" message, but when I refresh the same page laravel redirects me to:

```
http://localhost/home
```

I could not solve this and I have moved my first route out of the route group now everything is working well. If I keep it in the route group with `auth` & `web` middlewares it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `web` middleware [if you're using 5.2.27 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade).

Comment: Yes. Thanks it solve my problem. I have changed the code as Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function ()