# Fresh Install Laravel 5.2 Make:Auth onRegister does nothing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've been stuck on this issue for ages and I'm clueless on why it's not working, I've searched the internet and cannot find a solution. Whenever I register a user it just returns to `/register` no error. I can successfully `php artisan migrate` and it creates tables in my db in mysql.

Any help would be appreciated?

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
 Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
 Route::auth();
});
```

Thanks.

**Note: There is no error being displayed.**

**register.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**AuthController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you change the view and controller files after u made php artisan make:auth? share ur view and ur controller pls

Comment: Okay. Which views do you wanna see?

Comment: /register  and AUthcontroller

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Added my view and controller

Comment: vefore the Return User::create try to add dd($data['name']); and test again and tell me what u see

Comment: and try to put the route:auth(); before the route::get

Comment: `dd($data['name']);` Add that?

Comment: yes that should dump the name in the screen, i need to now whats going on

Comment: Nope nothing came on screen. :l

Comment: Yep it was my HTTPS.. Is there anyway to use https ?

Comment: so when disabled it worked?

Comment: Yeah.... how do I get it to post over HTTPS?

Comment: u need a secure login form, data must be encrypted when submitted, i dont know how to be honest, ask another question separate on that! , its a good question i think

Comment: Route::post('/register', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@register', 'https' => true]);

Comment: I'll give it a go :)

Comment: Doesn't work, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `web` middleware from `routes.php` [if you're on 5.2.27 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade).

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: Did that, still returning nothing on `/register`

Comment: When you mean remove `web` do you mean the line `['middleware' => 'web']` ?

Comment: You can remove whole `group` clause.

Comment: Okay I did that still returning to that `/register` page. :(

Comment: Does Laravel add registered users to a DB?

Comment: Nope. Nothing is being added to DB

Comment: If you're not getting any error, look in Laravel error log. There must be something.

Comment: Nope.. nothing is being logged inside the laravel.log