# "Session store not set on request" Error on Laravel

Tags: laravel, session, routes, middleware

I meet `Session store not set on request` error on Laravel5.2.
But general solution is write

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    // routes file  
});
```

But this code is already write on my `routes.php`

Why this error apper?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 5.2.27 or hgher, [try to remove `web` middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade) or just temporarily comment it for testing purposes:

So, just do this:

```
//Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    routes file  
//});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using laravel 5.2.31. And if I remove ```Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){ routes file });``` the error is disappered.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I accidentally downvoted this yesterday when I wanted to upvote it. Didn't realise until now, but I can't change my vote unless you edit the answer. If you'd like to do that, I'd be happy to change the vote. Sorry about the trouble. :(

Comment: @JoelHinz, it happens, don't worry about this. ) And thanks for doing this.