# Laravel errors array is empty in view but with content if I remove web middleware in routes

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

my controller

```
public function basicSettingStore(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'appid' => 'required',
        'appsecret' => 'required',
        'token' => 'required'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('weChat/basicSetting')->withErrors($validator);
    }
```

my routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {...
```

If the Route has 'web' middleware,the errors will be empty in view.But,if I remove it,the errors will be ok in view.

Can someone help me to access errors from $errors variable in my blade view? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 5.2.27 you have to remove `web` middleware from `routes.php`, because it's now added to all routes in this file automatically. If you add it manually, you can have problems with sessions, errors bag etc. Please read more on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784408/1227923).