# Laravel - can't access to error bag

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can't see any validation error, the `$errors` is always empty and I can't figured out why.
I have do this million times but in this project I do not see the problem.

Here the form:

```
@if( count( $errors ) > 0 )
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach( $errors->all() as $error )
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    {{ Form::open(['url'=>route('admin.roles.store'), 'method'=>'post']) }}
        <input type="text" name="name">
        {{ Form::submit() }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Here my Controller method:

```
public function store(CreateRoleRequest $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

The route use a middleware group:

```
'backend' => [
            'auth',
            \App\Http\Middleware\Boilerplate\CheckIfUserCanAccessToBackend::class
        ]
```

And this is the middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware\Boilerplate;

use Closure;

class CheckIfUserCanAccessToBackend
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        // Admin can access
        if( $user->hasRole('admin') )
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        // The user has the permission?
        if($user->can('access_backend') ){

            return $next($request);
        }

        // Can't access
        return abort(403);
    }
}
```

I have no idea about whats going on, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that can cause this problem is adding `web` middleware manually to `routes.php` routes [in Laravel 5.2.27 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade).

Comment: Just spended 2 days on this...thanks, I removed the `web` middleware and now it works!