# Laravel 5.2 redirect back with success message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a success message back to my home page on laravel.

```
return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('IT WORKS!');
```

For some reason the variable $success doesn't get any value after running this code.

The code I'm using to display the succes message:

```
@if (!empty($success))
    <h1>{{$success}}</h1>
@endif
```

I have added the home and newsletter page to the web middleware group in routes.php like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    });

    Route::post('/newsletter/subscribe','NewsletterController@subscribe');
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You should remove `web` middleware from `routes.php`. Adding `web` middleware manually causes [session and request related problems in Laravel 5.2.27 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade).

If it didn't help (still, keep `routes.php` without web middleware), you can try little bit different approach:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'IT WORKS!');
```

Displaying message if it exists:

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Good to know its not needed anymore. But after removing `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {` from my routes.php the `$success` variable still seems to be empty so that doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Comment: Doesn't work either It just doesn't seem to pass the message trough it stays empty.

Comment: Check if  Laravel creates session files at `storage\framework\sessions`. Or  if it adds data to `sessions` table if you use DB).

Comment: Yes it adds data to to `storage\framework\sessions` so that seems to work

Comment: Me and my friend looked again at your code and I did something wrong with your last solution it works now :-)

Answer (score 36):

you can use this :

```
return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('IT WORKS!');
```

and use this in your view :

```
@if(session('success'))
    <h1>{{session('success')}}</h1>
@endif
```

Comment: using this method does the session variable will remain persistent or just for once?

Comment: @AmitShah look at this link : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Answer (score 16):

Controller:

```
return redirect()->route('subscriptions.index')->withSuccess(['Success Message here!']);
```

Blade

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    @if(is_array(session('success')))
        <ul>
            @foreach (session('success') as $message)
                <li>{{ $message }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @else
        {{ session('success') }}
    @endif
</div>
@endif
```

You can always save this part as separate blade file and include it easily.
fore example:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @include('admin.system.success')
            <div class="box box-widget">
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it is the only one that treats the success messages as an Array, thus being possible to have multiple success messages displayed at once.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use `back()` function to redirect no need to use `redirect()->back()` make sure you are using 5.2 or greater than 5.2 version.

You can replace your code to below code.

```
return back()->with('message', 'WORKS!');
```

In the view file replace below code.

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

For more detail, you can read [here](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/implement-flash-message-with-laravel-57example.html)

`back()` is just a helper function. It's doing the same thing as `redirect()->back()`

Answer (score 6):

One way to do that is sending the message in the session like this:

**Controller:**

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'IT WORKS!');
```

**View**:

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
    <h1>{{ session('success') }}</h1>
@endif
```

And other way to do that is just creating the session and put the text in the view directly:

**Controller**:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', true);
```

**View**:

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
    <h1>IT WORKS!</h1>
@endif
```

You can check the full documentation here: [Redirecting With Flashed Session Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

I hope it is very helpful, regards.

Answer (score 4):

All of the above are correct, but try this straight one-liner:

`{{session()->has('message') ? session()->get('message') : ''}}`

Answer (score 4):

**In Controller**

```
return redirect()->route('company')->with('update', 'Content has been updated successfully!');
```

**In view**

```
@if (session('update'))
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable custom-success-box" style="margin: 15px;">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
     <strong> {{ session('update') }} </strong>
  </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

***in Controller:***

```
 `return redirect()->route('car.index')->withSuccess('Bein ajoute')`;
```

***In view***

```
  @if(Session::get('success'))
           <div class="alert alert-success">
               {{session::get('success')}}
           </div>
   @endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use laravel MessageBag to add our own messages to existing messages.

To use MessageBag you need to use:

```
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
```

In the controller:

```
MessageBag $message_bag

$message_bag->add('message', trans('auth.confirmation-success'));

return redirect('login')->withSuccess($message_bag);
```

Hope it will help some one.

- Adi

Comment: But... how to use it in view?