# Flash message is not shown when use withSuccess() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all, I was creating CRUD operation for my project and wanted to ensure that after user creates new record he or she would redirect to a certain page and with success message thus I decided to use `withSuccess()` but even if new record is added success message is not shown. The code I use:

```
Route::post('/contact/submit', function (Request $request) {
    $contact=new Contact();
    $contact->FirstName=$request->input('FirstName');
    $contact->LastName=$request->input('LastName');
    $contact->Age=$request->input('Age');
    $contact->save();
   return redirect('/contact')->withSuccess('Created');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use like this

```
 return redirect('/contact')->with('message', 'IT WORKS!');
```

or

```
return redirect('/contact')->withSuccess('IT WORKS!');
```

or

```
Session::flash('message','IT WORKS!'); //<--FLASH MESSAGE

return redirect('/contact');
```

and to display data on view use like this

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

use like this to display on view if you used `withSuccess()` method

```
@if(session('success'))
    <h1>{{session('success')}}</h1>
@endif
```

Comment: thank you dude for your great solution, but look why with('success') works properly with controllers, that is, if I use resource controller for CRUD then I do not have to add the code that you provided and all works properly

Comment: come on dude if it weren't important, I wouldn't ask your explanation

Comment: @Mirasan it may me a middleware issue, add the web middleware for your route and then check

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this in your `view` file:

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Check here :
[Laravel 5.2 redirect back with success message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376168/laravel-5-2-redirect-back-with-success-message)

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow the below steps:

1) In view file

@if(\Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{\Session::get('success')}}
    </div>
@endif


2) In controller function:
use with() function in place of withSuccess()

return redirect('/contact')->with('success', 'Information has been added Successfully!!');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using named routes for redirects. In case anyone finds themselves facing the same problem, using the `route()` method seems to redirect correctly and flash the message.

```php
return redirect(route('my-teams.index'))->withSuccess('Success message.');
```

The issue I encountered is that, it is possible to use the route name directly, but it does not flash the success message. The following code redirects correctly without flashing the message:

```php
return redirect('my-teams.index')->withSuccess('Success message.');
```