# Laravel 5 duplicate web middleware in route list

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I've just started a new Laravel 5.2 project and I have a problem with my routes. Web middleware is duplicated in route list and I have a lot of problems with sessions and csrf .

Here is my artisan route:list output:

```
+--------+----------+----------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                              | Name                       | Action                                                          | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                                |                            | Closure                                                         | web,web      |
|        | GET|HEAD | cron/cursos                      | cron_courses               | App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@call_store                | web,web      |
|        | GET|HEAD | cursos                           | courses                    | App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@index                     | web,web      |
|        | GET|HEAD | cursos/buscar                    | courses_search             | App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@search                    | web,web      |
|        | GET|HEAD | cursos/detalle/{id}              | courses_detail             | App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@detail                    | web,web      |
|        | GET|HEAD | cursos/solicitar/{id}            | courses_apply              | App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@apply                     | web,web,auth |
|        | POST     | guardar-datos                    | save_panel                 | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@panel_save                  | web,web,auth |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                             |                            | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | login                            |                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                            |                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                           |                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | panel                            | panel                      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@panel                       | web,web,auth |
|        | POST     | password/email                   |                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | password/reset                   |                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token?}          |                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | prueba                           | prueba                     | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@prueba                      | web,web      |
|        | POST     | register                         |                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                         |                            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | sociallogin/callback/{provider?} | auth.getSocialAuthCallback | App\Http\Controllers\AuthSocialController@getSocialAuthCallback | web,web      |
|        | GET|HEAD | sociallogin/{provider?}          | auth.getSocialAuth         | App\Http\Controllers\AuthSocialController@getSocialAuth         | web,web      |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

And here is my routes.php file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/prueba', ['as' => 'prueba', 'uses' => 'UserController@prueba']);

    # HOME
    Route::get('/cursos',              ['as' => 'courses',        'uses' => 'CourseController@index']);
    Route::get('/cursos/buscar',       ['as' => 'courses_search', 'uses' => 'CourseController@search']);
    Route::get('/cursos/detalle/{id}', ['as' => 'courses_detail', 'uses' => 'CourseController@detail']);

    # SOCIAL LOGIN
    Route::get('/sociallogin/{provider?}',[
        'uses' => 'AuthSocialController@getSocialAuth',
        'as'   => 'auth.getSocialAuth'
    ]);
    Route::get('/sociallogin/callback/{provider?}',[
        'uses' => 'AuthSocialController@getSocialAuthCallback',
        'as'   => 'auth.getSocialAuthCallback'
    ]);

});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'cron', 'middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/cursos',       ['as' => 'cron_courses', 'uses' => 'CourseController@call_store']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/panel',          ['as' => 'panel',      'uses' => 'UserController@panel']);
    Route::post('/guardar-datos', ['as' => 'save_panel', 'uses' => 'UserController@panel_save']);

    Route::get('/cursos/solicitar/{id}', ['as' => 'courses_apply', 'uses' => 'CourseController@apply']);

});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

I have another project with Laravel 5.2 and I everything is working fine.

Any idea how to solve it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `web` middleware from `routes.php`, because [since 5.2.27 Laravel applies `web` middleware automatically to all routes in `routes.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you have an extra route group in your routes.php file. Remove that route group and it should be fixed.

Laravel uses the 'web' middleware by default behind the scenes in the latest versions of 5.2!