# Success and error message does'nt show

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello i am new to laravel i created page to added single post but for some reason success and errors messages doesn't appear at all not matter i successfully insert a new post or submit empty form although some fields are required .. in my controller i am using this method `postCreatePost`

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\Catgory;

class PostController extends Controller {
    public function getBlogIndex() {
        return view ('frontend.blog.index');
    }

public function getSignlePost($post_id, $end = 'frontend') {
    return view ($end, '.blog.single');
}

public function getCreatePost() {
    return view('admin.blog.create_post');
}

public function postCreatePost(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'     => 'required|max:120|unique:posts',
        'author'    => 'required|max:80',
        'body'      => 'required'
    ]);

    $post           = new Post();
    $post->title    = $request['title'];
    $post->author   = $request['author'];
    $post->body     = $request['body'];

    $post->save();

    //Attaching categories

    return redirect()->route('admin.index')->with(['success','Post sucessfully created!']);
}
}
```

This is my view

```
@extends('layouts.admin-master')

@section('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::secure('src/css/form.css') }}" type="text/css" />
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        @section('styles')
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('src/css/common.css') }}" type="text/css" />
        @append

    @if(Session::has('fail'))
        <section class="info-box fail">
            {{ Session::get('fail') }}
        </section>
    @endif

    {{ var_dump(Session::get('success')) }}

    @if(Session::has('success'))
        <section class="info-box success">
            {{ Session::get('success') }}
        </section>
    @endif

    @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <section class="info-box fail">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </section>
    @endif

    <form action="{{ route('admin.blog.post.create') }}" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'claass=has-error' : '' }} />
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="author">Author</label>
            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" {{ $errors->has('author') ? 'claass=has-error' : '' }} />
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="category_select">Add Categories</label>
            <select name="category_select" id="category_select">
                <!-- Foreach loop to output categories -->
                <option value="Dummy Category ID">Dummy Category</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Add Category</button>
            <div class="added-categories">
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="categories" id="categories">

        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="body">Body</label>
            <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="10" {{ $errors->has('body') ? 'claass=has-error' : '' }}></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn">Create Post</button>

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
    </form>
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::secure('src/js/posts.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

My routes inside web middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {    
Route::get('/about', function() {
    return view('frontend.other.about');
})->name('about');


Route::group([
    'prefix'    => '/admin'    
], function() {
    Route::get('/', [
        'uses'  => 'AdminController@getIndex',
        'as'    => 'admin.index'
    ]);

    Route::get('/blog/posts/create', [
        'uses'  => 'PostController@getCreatePost',
        'as'    => 'admin.blog.create_post'
    ]);

    Route::post('/blog/post/create', [
        'uses'  => 'PostController@postCreatePost',
        'as'    => 'admin.blog.post.create'
    ]);
});
});
```

And the model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'posts_categories');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove `web` middleware - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade

Comment: Thank you for the tip i didn't know that and it helped fixing my issue

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong syntax. Try this one:

```
return redirect()->route('admin.index')->with('success','Post sucessfully created!');
```