# TokenMismatchException after using web middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

im adding csrf_field to all my forms by default and it was working fine , i decided to store some data in session so i've grouped some routes and used `web` middlewar on them

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['category' , 'web']], function () {
     Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
     Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
})
```

now when i submit a form i get this error

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

but they work fine if i remove web middleware !!

im using database drive for my sessions ... i dont know if that's relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Remove `web` middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade), that should fix the problem.

Since 5.2.27 `web` middleware applies automatically to all routes (in 5.3 to all routes in `routes/web.php`) and you shouldn't add it manually.

Comment: i want to use session , session start is in web middleware apparently

Comment: @hretic, yes, you'll be able to use sessions after you remove web middleware since it applies automatically.

Comment: thanx  it worked , funny thing i had problem with getting my session to work and i red somewhere since 5.2 i should use web middleware to solve it  ... and there goes 1 hour of my time !

Answer (score 0):

If the form is not token field _token

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: "im adding csrf_field to all my forms by default" - This is already being handled.