# Session in middleware don't working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm storing a value in session in my middleware:

but when I refresh or go to new page the sessions is null.
what I do wrong?

```
class WorkflowContextMiddleware
{
    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector|mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $types = $request->input('types', []);

        foreach ($types as $type => $context) {
            $request->session()->put("somekey.contexts.{$type}", $context);
            $request->session()->save();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**route:**

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalisation::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => ['web','localise','localeSessionRedirect']
], function () {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        (new \Illuminate\Support\Debug\Dumper)->dump(\Session::get('somekey'));
    });
});
```

route provider:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'Arcanine\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        //

        parent::boot($router);
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \App\Workflow\Http\Middleware\WorkflowContextMiddleware::class,
    ],
```

Comment: where does `public function getContext(string $type)` called? also, what is `$workflowContext`? also, how did you register your `middleware` to your route?

Comment: Are you using ```Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']])``` for the controller method ```getContext()```?

Comment: What is `$manager` in your middleware constructor - I mean interface / type? I assume that your setType and getContext methods are defined on $manager, but do not see what class/interface/type you are referencing for DI. Try to check with using `session()->put()` in the foreach loop of the handle method, what does your route closure return.

Comment: @BagusTesa: yes, i'm using web middleware. Donkarnash: same result

Comment: May be not an issue but can you check if there are sessions in `/storage/framework/sessions` just to rule out the possibility of file permission issues where laravel is not able to persist the sessions. Another check to make is for the `lifetime` and `expire_on_close' => false` in `config\session.php` - I guess no harm in checking

Comment: I think in your middleware's handle method using `$request->session()->put("somekey.contexts.{$type}", $context)` would be more appropriate. And one more thing, the code provided above in your question does not show the middleware `WorkflowContextMiddleware` being applied to the route group.

Comment: @Donkarnash I edit the question. I added the middleware on web group. the session works in all application. only doesn't work in middleware.

Comment: I tried to test your code, in L5.3 - it works. Check to see if your `$types` array is getting populated in the handle() method of the middleware or is it being passed to the foreach loop as an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your session to work, wrap all your routes within:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: This will stop session working in 5.2.27 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `web` middleware from route group if you're [using 5.2.27 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade).

The thing is all routes in `web.php` are already using `web` middleware and adding it manually will cause problems with sessions.

Comment: my routes provider don't apply web middleware by default