# Laravel 5, nothing displayed when form submit button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am using Laravel 5.3, the task that i am currently working on is the Form routing.

This is my routes.php file.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@login']);
    Route::post('/handleLogin', ['as' => 'handleLogin', 'uses' => 'LoginController@handleLogin']);
});
```

The actual Form code in the view.

```
    {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'handleLogin')) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('email') !!}
    {!! Form::text('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('password') !!}
  {!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::token() !!}
{!! Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The controller that has the handle function.

```
/* handleLogin function to request the data*/
public function handleLogin(Request $request){
    $data = $request-> only('email', 'password');
    if(\Auth::attempt($data)){
        return 'Is Logged In';
    return redirect()-> intended('/home');
    }

return back()->withInput();
}
```

When i click on Login button, a blank page is displayed instead of the page that would display 'Is Logged In'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just remove this `return 'Is Logged In';`

Comment: I want the page to display Is Logged In for testing purpose, but i'm just getting a blank page. Why is that happening?

Comment: Just get rid of it and try....this is for testing purposes too!

Comment: nope, now it says error loading page

Comment: And where do you have your `home` route?

Comment: Route::post('/home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'UsersController@home']);

Answer (score 0):

You should [remove `web` middleware from routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade) file since you're using Laravel 5.3 in which `web` middleware is added automatically. Adding it manually will cause problems.

Comment: I tried that now, but when i submit the form i still get a blank page...

Comment: Check for the last error in `/storage/logs/laravel.log`. Also, do not put `web` middleware back into routes file.

Comment: This is not an error, it's stack trace. Look right above stack trace (above #0).

Comment: Sorry. This is the last error [2016-11-21 12:10:48] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/vagrant/Code/steelworks/routes/web.php:22

Comment: If it has timestamp of the moment when you're getting empty page, please post `web.php` somewhere.