# Session not working in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-variables, laravel-5.3

I am trying to create session like below code but session not working please sussgest me any soluton.

**Save**

```
$data = array(
   "id" => $row->id,
   "name" => $row->name
);

Session($data);
```

**Fetch**

```
Session('id');
```

I also tried web middleware but till the same session not working

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function ()
{

});
```

Comment: Where you are trying ? In controller or anywhere else?

Comment: i m saving and retrieving session in model class

Comment: Did any answer given below worked for you ?

Comment: Share your model also.

Answer (score 13):

I have recently solved this issue.

If you are trying to save array in session or if you want to push data into the session this try following.

> **Solution:**

First go to Kernel.php into the "App\Http\Kernel.php" and add this line  `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` into the $middleware array. This will start storing the data.

[image]

---

**For session array**

`Session::push('cart', $product);`

---

**For Single value**

Replace session_key with the variable you want.

`Session::put('session_key');`

Reference: https://www.scratchcode.io/session-not-working-in-laravel/

Comment: Yes! Adding the `StartSession` middleware to the list of "global" middlewares in Kernel.php is what solved it for me ...

Answer (score 4):

You should [remove `web` middleware from routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade) to fix the problem with sessions.

Also correct syntax for persisting data is:

```
session(['key' => $data]);
```

To get data use:

```
session('key');
```

Comment: i am not using now middleware but issue till same.

Comment: Using `web` middleware will definetely break sessions, so check if you added it manually somewhere else. Also, run `php artisan route:clear` command to clear route cache.

Answer (score 4):

Session will be working fine if the following step can be followed...

**First Step:**

Add the following code inside a controller(where Session will be used to save data)

```
use Session;
```

**Second Step:**

Inside a method of that controller,  Session code like below:

```
Session::put('name', 'Sabuz'); 
Session::put('data', $data);
```

any data can be saved but make sure first parameter of put method is key and second is its value

**Third Step:**

That data can be viewed from anywhere with the below command as long as session caries that data

```
$name = Session::get('name'); //get method just use the key of a put method
echo $name;
```

Hopefully, it will be workable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want persistence sessions, use `session()->save()` or `Session::save()`

```
$data = array("id" => $row->id, "name" => $row->name);

session($data);
//or
session()->put('key', 'value');

session()->save();

echo session('id');
```

Also, the 'storage' directory should have write permission.

```
chmod -R a+rw storage/
```

Answer (score 0):

My session is not working because I tried to put and fetch in controller constructor and Laravel 5.3 not supporting directly put and fetch session in a constructor. If you want to put and fetch session in a constructor you need to add below code in a constructor.

```
function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware(function ($request, $next)
   {

   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of writing to sessions 1st time per session working, but updates not working.

The fix was the old classic...

```
use Session;
```

Answer (score -1):

Save the data

```
session()->put('data' => $data);
```

Get the data

```
session()->get('data');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use session like

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

Set Session:

```
 Session::flash('key', 'Value');
```

View File :

```
@if(Session::has('key'))
        <div class="alert-success">
            {{ Session::get('key') }}
        </div>
@endif
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades#facade-class-reference
https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Session.html