# Auth middleware in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

i've a problem with middleware in laravel.I wanted to make an middleware that would allow just registered users sign in. And 'yes' i know that i could get that by 'php artisan make:auth' but i wanted to make my own middleware.
if i type in url '/dashboard' it redirects me to dashboard what is really bad 
and also works for signing in

So i wrote middleware:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::guard()->guest()) {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then added it to routes in kernel.php:

```
'auth_user'=>\App\Http\Middleware\AuthUser::class
```

Here are my routes:

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

Route::post('/signup',[
    'uses'=>'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as'=>'signup'
]);
Route::post('/signin',[
    'uses' =>'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as'  =>'signin'
]);

Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth_user']],function (){
    Route::get('/dashboard',[
        'uses'       =>  'UserController@getDashboard',
        'as'        =>  'dashboard',
    ]);
});
```

And my UserController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getDashboard()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }
    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email'     =>  'email|unique:users',
            'first_name'=>  'required|max:128',
            'password'  =>  'required|min:6'
        ]);
        $email=$request['email'];
        $password=bcrypt($request['password']);
        $first_name=$request['first_name'];
        $surname=($request['surname']);
        $user=new User();

        $user->email=$email;
        $user->password=$password;
        $user->first_name=$first_name;
        $user->surname=$surname;

        $user->save();
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email'     =>  'required|email',
            'password'  =>  'required|min:6'
        ]);

 if(Auth::attempt(['email'    => $request['email'], 'password'       
            =>$request['password']]))      
        {

            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
            return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: In 5.4 you [shouldn't add `web` middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade) to the routes in the `web.php`.

Comment: i deleted it from routes but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have the 'web' middleware when defining routes in routes/web.php.

It's applied to routes/web.php routes through your RoutingServiceProvider by default

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth_user']],function (){
    Route::get('/dashboard',[
       'uses'       =>  'UserController@getDashboard',
       'as'        =>  'dashboard',
    ]);
});
```

Comment: thanks, now if i type /dashboard i get redirect to backpage but if i sign in it doesn't redirect to dashboard

Comment: maybe the problem is in middleware class

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

Route::post('/signup',[
    'uses'=>'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as'=>'signup'
]);
Route::post('/signin',[
    'uses' =>'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as'  =>'signin'
]);

Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth_user']],function (){
    Route::get('/dashboard',[
        'uses'       =>  'UserController@getDashboard',
        'as'        =>  'dashboard',
    ]);
});