# Can't login, attempt always fails

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to perform the login of the user but the attempt always returns false

CONTROLLER

```
 public function login(Request $request)
      {
      $validator = Validator($request->all(),[
           'username' => 'required',
           'password' => 'required|alpha_num',
      ]);
      if ($validator->fails()){
           dd($validator->messages()->toJson());
      }else{
           User::login($request);
           dd(Auth::check());
      }
 }
```

MODEL

```
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class User extends Authenticatable
 {
      protected $table = 'user';
      protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
      public $timestamps = false;

 /** The rules to validate a new user
 * @var array
 */
 static $rulesRegister = array(
      'username' => 'required|unique:user,Username',
      'password' => 'required|alpha_num',
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:user,Email',
 );

 /** Login the user in the App
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Return True or False (?, need dd)
 */
 static function login(Request $request)
 {
      Auth::attempt([
           'Username' => $request->input('username'),
           'Password' => $request->input('password')
      ]
      ,true);
 }
```

FORM

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('login') }}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="">
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="">
      <button type="submit">
           Login
        </button>
 </form>
```

ROUTES

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
      Route::get('/', function () {
           return view('index');
      })->name('index');

      Route::post('/login', 'UserController@login')->name('login');
 });
```

I already debuged the DatabaseUserProvider -> method retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials) and the credentials or query is always null,
i already tried to rename my Password and Username to all lower case (in database and in the attempt() method), i tried to attempt with and without bcrypt, tried by Email i can't seem to find what is happening

Comment: You should not apply `web` middleware to the routes in `web.php` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade

Comment: it worked lol, thanks man