# ReflectionException - Middleware class does not exist Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know that I am not the first one with such a problem. I have read all the existing information on Stackoverflow and other sources but it could not solve my problem that I always will get a `ReflectionException` `Class App\Http\Middleware\xxx does not exist`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware\xxx;

use Closure;

class xxx
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

No joke, this is really my class. I have renamed it to `xxx` to avoid typo.

All my routes will pass the `web` and `admin` Middleware:

```
Route::middleware(['web', 'admin'])->group(function() {
```

And this is my `/app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\xxx::class,
    ],
```

- File is named `xxx.php` and it location is `App\Http\Middleware\`.
- Namespace is correct
- composer dump-autoload will not solve the problem

I also tried to modify my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories",
        "App/Http/Middleware/xxx.php"
    ],
```

which caused following warning:

```
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Middleware\xxx\xxx" was found in both "$baseDir . '/app/Http/Middleware/xxx.php" and "/code/App/Http/Middleware/xxx.php", the first will be used.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, change namespace to:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
```

Then remove `"App/Http/Middleware/xxx.php"` from `composer.json` and run `composer du`

You also, need to [remove web middleware from the routes file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784408/1227923) if you're using 5.2.27 and higher:

```
Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function() {
```

Answer (score 3):

You may have cached files in `bootstrap/cache` directory. Delete those and composer dumpautoload again.

If that too fails, delete your entire vendor directory and delete `composer.lock` and then run `composer install`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your namespace to -

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
```