# Auth::user session is not persistent

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a dummy project to know more about middlewares. I want to create custom registration for this project.

I changed 1

- User Model
- users Table
- Login Controller

For now I don't need a registration page. I just filled a dummy data in users table. I want to see how this auth middle ware works for a group of routes.

So, After that I tried logging in using the same credentials. I was able to log in however, If I want to navigate other pages its throwing a login in page. Somehow, Auth is getting destroyed.

What am I missing here?

Here is my route file

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {
    Route::view('/home', 'home')->name('home');
    Route::view('something','SuperAdmin.something')->name('something');
});
```

This is my Login Controller

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use Auth;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {          
        use AuthenticatesUsers;

        protected $redirectTo = '/home';

        public function login(Request $request){
            $email = trim($request->email);
            $password = $request->password;

            if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])){
                return view('SuperAdmin.dashboard');
            }
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }
    }
```

I am redirecting to {{something}} view from home.blade.php. The Auth works for just one page.

How can I get it working as default?

Comment: [Remove `web` middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784408/1227923)

Comment: No, it's still the same.

Comment: I am routing to new blade and, the app is showing the Login and register. ie;  this user is guest. No longer authenticated.