# How to display error with Session:get() and withErrors()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have stack of calls in controller:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
```

The function `withErrors` takes array of errors.

How can I display there messages in template?

I tried:

```
{{Session::get('MessageBag')}}
```

So, the latest edition is:

```
 $errors = $validator->messages(); // Here I get $error with fillied data
            return redirect('tour/create')
                ->withErrors($errors)
                ->withInput();
```

In template I do:

```
{{count($errors)}}
```

It gives me zero

Comment: I have found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36379183/6605573

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In view file access errors with `$errors`

```
{{$errors->first('MessageBag')}}
```

Try to `print $errors print_r($errors)`. It is global variable for views.

Comment: It does not work, I dont see messages, may be due to `Redirect`?

Comment: If do `{{dd($errors)}}` in teplate I get: "#bags: []"

Comment: For validation I use: `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [])`

Comment: it should be Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'heading' => 'required',
   'subheading' => 'required',
   'description' => 'required',
   'id_holiday_type' => 'required|max:10',
   'total_floors' => 'required|max:10',
   #'floor_space' => 'required',
   #'ground_size' => 'required',
   'accommondation_style' => 'required',
   'swimming_pool' => 'required',
   'internet_access' => 'required',
  ]);

Comment: When I do `dd($validator)` I get NULL

Answer (score 2):

Try this you can see whether the data is available

```
  {{ dd(Request::session()) }}
```

Comment: Problem was in `middleware`