# Why does not work withErrors in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use `withErrors()` to pass validation messages in template blade:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            dd($validator); // Gives me filled array with messages
            return Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
```

In template I have:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

I am guess that problem in  the call stack of templates blade, or in function `withErrors`.

If `withErrors` uses session, maybe this is one of problem.

Additionally this is my call validation:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            "name" => 'required|string|min:10',
            "text" => 'required|string|min:10',
        ]);
```

Comment: In view page what is the output of dd($errors)

Comment: `ViewErrorBag {#255 ▼
  #bags: []
}`

Comment: please try dd($errors->toArray())

Comment: So no error is passed to view. May be no validation error(double check). You may also laravel error log in storage/log directory because it seems that you are doing right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ErrorBag is always empty in Laravel 5.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377420/errorbag-is-always-empty-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: Yes, it helped me, problem was in routing. Thank for useful link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in view:

```
@if(Session::has('error'))
    {{ Session::get('error') }}
@endif
```

Comment: No result, again empty